# How to concatenate two fields from a csv

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to remove files from a server.  I have a csv that contains the path in one field and the name of the file in another field.  I'd like to concatenate the two fields together so that I delete only the files that are specified (otherwise it would just delete everything in the path).
Here's the nonworking code with the two field names that I need to reference:

```
Import-Csv C:\CSVs\TestDelete.csv | Foreach-Object {
    Remove-Item -LiteralPath  $_.Path + $_.Name -WhatIf 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assumes your 'path' data has a trailing '\':

```
Import-Csv C:\CSVs\TestDelete.csv | Foreach-Object{
Remove-Item -LiteralPath ($_.Path + $_.Name) -WhatIf 
}
```

Comment: Perfect!  I didn't have the trailing "\", but that was easy enough to add back in.  I was just missing the "()"

Comment: [`Join-Path`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113347) is also useful for dealing with arbitrary inputs (e.g. `-LiteralPath (Join-Path $_.Path $_.Name)`).